# How to index an XML file in Solr that is not structured the way Solr expects?

Tags: xml, indexing, solr

I am using Solr 8.0.0 on windows. I have been able to successfully run it on pdf and csv files. However I am not able to run on a well structured custom xml file.

As per the guides the xml files need to follow the following structure so that solr can index the document properly (identify the correct fields) for searching-

```
<add> 
   <doc> 
      <field name = "id">001</field> 
      <field name = "name">Jon Doe</field> 
   </doc>
   ...
</add>
```

However the xml file that I need to index has the following well defined structure (thousands of rows) -

```
<tags>
  <row Id="1" TagName=".net" Count="280415" ExcerptPostId="3624959" WikiPostId="3607476" />
  <row Id="2" TagName="html" Count="806983" ExcerptPostId="3673183" WikiPostId="3673182" />
...
</tags>
```

When I posted this xml and queried then I got no results whatsoever. However uploading a dummy xml whose structure follows the guidelines works automatically.

I think that I may have to manually write the `managed-schema` file, but I couldn't find any guides/tutorials on how to do that.

Any help or resources would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think tweaking the managed-schema will help you here. One option is for you to write code (or an XSLT transformation) to get your original XML to the XML that Solr expects. Another option is to look at the Data Import Handler https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

Answer (score 1):

I am agree with Hector Correa, if you don't can change the xml file its the best way to use a xslt file to handle this. But notice you can only use xslt version 1! (maybe now you can use v2 also but check it before please)

here a small example(hint) how it can looks like, I haven't test it yet!

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
<xslt:template match='/'>
    <xsl:for-each select='tags/row'>
        <field name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@Id" /></field>
        <field name="tagname"><xsl:value-of select="@TagName" /></field>
        <field name="count"><xsl:value-of select="@Count" /></field>
        <field name="excerptpostid"><xsl:value-of select="@ExcerptPostId" /></field>
        <field name="wikipostid"><xsl:value-of select="@WikiPostId" /></field>
    </xsl:for-each>>
</xslt:template>
```

The field names are from your managed-schema as well